# Matlab cannot import a matrixmarket file

Tags: matlab

I've been using [mmread](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/mmio/matlab/mmiomatlab.html) on Matlab to import MatrixMarket files.
But it doesn't work for the .mtx file [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE108699), although it works for the .mtx file [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2396856). The error message is: Output argument "A" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"mmread".

Command:

```
temp=mmread('GSM2396856_dc_3hr.mtx.txt');
```

Comment: Please show us exactly how you are calling `mmread`.

Comment: just added the code

Comment: That error suggests a bug in `mmread` (or a fault in the mtx file and poor error handling in mmread). I would try setting breakpoints on all the places in `mmread` where `A` is assigned so you can check that at least one of them is visited and see what's going wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

The function mmread only support 'field' as 'real, complex and pattern'. So if the field is indicated as integer,I got the same error report as yours. I would suggest you to change it to real. And also I think this is something the tool developer should add into the function.

Answer (score 1):

The function mmread does not support integer field. You can modify it by adding the following to mmread.

```
if  ( strcmp(field,'integer') )               % integer valued entries:

[T,count] = fscanf(mmfile,'%i',3);
T = [T; fscanf(mmfile,'%i')];
if ( size(T) ~= 3*entries )
   message = ...
   str2mat('Data file does not contain expected amount of data.',...
           'Check that number of data lines matches nonzero count.');
   disp(message);
   error('Invalid data.');
end
T = reshape(T,3,entries)';
A = sparse(T(:,1), T(:,2), T(:,3), rows , cols);
```

elseif  ( strcmp(field,'real') )               % real valued entries:
  ...................